# How to read the data from output cells?

Tags: cells

I have results of some calculation as a number of output cells in the saved .nb file. Since these results are obtained before (not during this run of  Mathematica), I cannot use % to access previous output. They are many so I cannot do this manually. I need to extract the results from the output cell into a single list automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [`NotebookImport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookImport). For example, here is a notebook saved as "example.nb":

```
nb = CreateDocument[{
    ExpressionCell[Defer[2+2],"Input"],
    ExpressionCell[4, "Output"],
    ExpressionCell[Defer[SparseArray[RandomInteger[10,10]]],"Input"],
    ExpressionCell[SparseArray[RandomInteger[10,10]],"Output"]
}];
NotebookSave[nb, FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory,"example.nb"}]]
```

Then, using [`NotebookImport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookImport):

```
NotebookImport[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory,"example.nb"}], "Output"] //InputForm
```

> {4, SparseArray[Automatic, {10}, 0, {1, {{0, 10}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, 
>       {8}, {9}, {10}}}, {5, 8, 2, 3, 7, 1, 8, 1, 9, 4}}]}

Answer (score 0):

Due to some reason,

```
NotebookImport[file, "Output"]
```

didn't work. It returned an empty array. I used

```
NBI=NotebookImport[file];
```

And then

```
ToExpression[NBI[[i]]]
```

in the loop.

Comment: What does `NotebookImport[file, _ -> "Cell"][[All, 2]]` return? Is "Output" not one of the possible cell styles?